# How to exit "wall" without pressing Ctrl+D?

Tags: linux, cron, wall

I'm using crontab to send messages to all users.

I wrote

```
*/1 * * * * wall $(bash some_shell_script.sh)
```

But the problem is I always have to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to end the message.

How can I solve this??

Comment: wall send it's argument from command line. does `bash some_shell_script.sh` terminate ?

Comment: The parameter to wall is a text file. What are you trying to do with this shell script?

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is as cron jobs are never interactive, and would therefore not be able to "wait for `Ctrl+D`".  Please show the script that you are using in that command substitution.

Comment: In my environment (Centos 8) after crontab task is executed (with wall in it) if I press CTRL+D I get exit from the "whole" shell...

Comment: As Kusulananda mentioned about cron is not interactive, I think OP should clarify more how he/she is able to get the possibility to enter CTRL+D to send messages and leave wall. Maybe he/she mixing running wall from inside crontab and running wall from shell directly...

Comment: @AnthonyKelly, my man page for wall gives the synopsis `wall [-n] [-t timeout] [message | file]`, so it looks like the argument can also be the message itself.

Comment: @ilkkachu Interesting, I was looking at the man page on MacOS, which provides this synopsis `wall [-g group] [file]`.

Comment: @AnthonyKelly, ok, it's different between systems, then! I looked at the [Debian man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/bsdutils/wall.1.en.html) (and made the mistake of generalizing to all Linuxen). The [FreeBSD one](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wall&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) indeed only says it takes a file, and then [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wall) only takes a message. They did tag with [tag:linux] so they probably don't have the FreeBSD one, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wall` command executes within the context of `cron`. It does its thing and exits.

On the receiving display devices (terminals) you will get the notification from `wall`. This notification cares nothing about what you are doing on the terminal, so if you are quietly sitting at a command line prompt when the notification message is sent, the prompt will not be rewritten. You have found that you need to hit enter to get the prompt re-sent, but in practical terms this is unnecessary: you could simply enter your command normally.

Scenario timeline

1. You are logged in and sitting at a command prompt
2. The `wall` notification is sent to your terminal
3. You type `ls` (and hit *Enter*)

At step 3 you do not have a visible prompt but the shell is still patiently waiting for your command.

---

Alternatively, perhaps you're actually talking about how you exit from the `crontab` command. In this instance the Ctrl/D is used to signal the end of input.

Scenario

1. `crontab`
2. You enter the line `*/1 * * * * bash some_shell_script.sh | wall`
3. You hit Ctrl/D to end data input to the `crontab` command

Note that the Ctrl/D in step 3 is nothing to do with `wall`. Also, this `crontab` entry will repeat your `wall` command every minute. Is that really what you want?

Comment: since cron invokes sh by default to parse the command line, I can't see how `wall $(bash some_shell_script.sh)` can ever makes sense as it passes the result of split+glob applied on the output of that bash command to `wall`. Likely the OP wants `bash some_shell_script.bash | wall` or `wall -- "$(bash some_shell_script.bash)"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas agreed, and I should probably have noted that. Here I'm simply copying the line of code provided from the OP. It might be that they are aiming for an effect similar to `bash _some_shell_script.sh | xargs` of course - we don't know

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought the wall command is not ended. But as you said wall is ended and I can just write a command like ls without typing enter. 
Frankly I don't know why this is happening but I'll try to figure out. Thank you

Comment: I mean why the prompt disappears? now I know I can type any command like prompt is in there but I want to know why prompt disappears

Comment: It had already been written

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU screen to isolate the process in the background without exiting.

1. Install GNU Screen for your distro
2. `screen -R wall`
3. `wall $(bash some_shell_script.sh)`
4. Ctrl-A, Ctrl-D

Comment: Just realized this is a cron job, what are you trying to do???

Comment: `wall` should just do its thing and exit, how does screen help here?